# log4net.ext.json for log4net version 1.2.13-old_key

Tags: json, log4net

I am using the log4net dll of version 1.2.13.0 built using the old key. I didn't find the version of log4net.Ext.Json to be used with this version of log4net. Could you please help? Also, after referring the md5 of log4net-1.2.13 [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi), I couldn't locate any of the md5 specified on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still in need of that fix?

You could possibly build it from [source](https://github.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json)

Alternatively, I'll suggest moving to new-key log4net if you can. (I guess you've considered that, alright :o)